# Lubuntu 16.04 Wifi not working

Tags: wifi, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo 3000 N200 laptop, but the "Wifi Networks" is greyed out. In the process of installing OS Wifi hasn't been recognized. Then I decided to reinstall Lubuntu but now with Ethernet cable plugged in. Installation was longer because of simultaneous updates but never the less, Wifi is not working (Ethernet does).

I did my research on: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322093 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 but not of that helped...

"sudo apt install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer" was mentioned on other forums as well but it didn't resolve my problem.

Previos OS on this laptop was Lubuntu 15.10 and the Wifi was working properly.

PS. I also tried to add my home Wifi manually (entering SSID, Mode, Device and other settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Installing “firmware-b43-installer” offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-firmware-b43-installer-offline)

You need to install `firmware-b43-installer`.

If you do not have an alternative internet connection, do it this way.

If you installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`, then remove it.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

1. Download these files

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

2. Copy them to your Ubuntu Home folder.
3. Run in terminal

```
    sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb
    tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
    sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

4. Reboot or run:

   `sudo modprobe b43`

**Note:** For 32-bit systems download http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_015-9_i386.deb instead of amd64 and update the file name in the dpkg command.

**For Lubuntu 16.04** http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb should be installed or the i386 alternative.

Comment: Hi, I did everything you said. Downloaded http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_015-9_i386.deb, because i have 32 bit i686 arhitecture. After downloading http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2, I copied those two files in home folder, then run: sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_015-9_i386.deb,
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2,
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o,
and rebooted, nothing changed, actually I got an error saying my installed pckg have unmet dependencies.

Comment: Use these commands to solve dependency problem.`sudo apt-get update –fix-missing;`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a;`
`sudo apt-get install -f;`

Comment: Please read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to answer, anyway, after solving dependency problem wifi is still not working.. I tried to install lubuntu willy 15.10 (from my old 2016 .iso file), but the wifi was disabled there also, even though it worked on that lubuntu as i said before...

Comment: Would you suggest completely wiping off my hard drive including currently installed lubuntu 16.04 and start all over again?
It is an old laptop which I actually don't need (but a good piece of hardware), and there are no files on hard drive...
So I can't lose anything..